# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) - C Arguments

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault, arguments, coredump

every time I run the program below in the following way: `./a.out -a -b` it runs properly. But if choose to run `./a.out -a`, I result in a segmentation fault (core dumped). Is there any way I can fix this?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[1],"-a") == 0)
        {...
        if (strcmp(argv[2],"-b") == 0)
        {...}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run it with `./a.out -a`, only one argument, then you should not do the check `strcmp(argv[2],"-b")`, because there is no third argument, and reading `argv[2]` would result in undefined behavior.

---

You can fix it by adding an extra check before doing the `strcmp(argv[2],"-b")`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[1],"-a") == 0)
        {...
        if (argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[2],"-b") == 0)
        {...}
        }
    }
}
```

This looks pretty ugly but it would work.

---

Answer (score 1):

argc counts all arguments, including the name of the program. 
If you don't supply a -b argument, then argc is equal to 2